# Dell UltraSharp U2421E - solid colors look pixelated with tiny white lines

Tags: display, external-display, display-settings

I connected a brand new **Dell UltraSharp U2421E monitor** to a brand new Dell Latitude 5520 laptop with Windows 10, resolution 1920 x 1200. I noticed at once that blue headers of windows that are **solid lighter blue looked pixelated.** I have tried older DELL laptop with the same result. On the image like this: [image: Default windows 10 bckg] it seems, that **there are many white vertical lines,** almost like I see individual pixels.
The same picture on the same computer - display mirroring - is OK on older DELL display.
The problem is similar to this issue
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/616564/i-can-see-a-grid-on-solid-colors-mostly-light-blue-acer-sb230-bbix

Lowering frequency is not an option since it is already 59.950 Hz. The problem is with other colors too but not so visible.
It is annoying, seems to strain my eyes, any advices here?

---

I have observed that the effect is observable from ceratin distance range, about 50-70 cm, and it less observable from bigger or lesser distance. Still I can see most of the icons on my desktop like composed of individual pixels, split with tiny lines.

---

Today I checked another piece of exactly the same type and it seems ok. Going to get a replacement.

---

Got a replacement LCD monitor, the effect is lesser, but still observable.

---

The problem is best observed when you move your head towards the display and back away, as you would normally sway and adjust on your chair. With that display it flickers a lot which strains eyes and I percieve it as rather unhealthy. With older or another displays like older ASUS or really old HP 17 inch there is no effect like that at all.

Comment: It is annoying, seems to strain my eyes, any advices here? ... Return for a different monitor.  Monitors are definitely not all created equal.

Comment: I will test another piece as soon as others in my office get their new displays.

Comment: Check antialias settings - 1920x1080 on a 24" monitor does mean that you will be able to see individual pixels from 12-18" away with decent eyesight. Most screens have a smaller dot pitch that that these days. Also, check what resolution the screen is **actually** running at - your screenshot is only 1366x768, which would show the effect even more.

Comment: It's pointless showing us a screenshot, as that is how the video card see's it and not how the monitor shows it.

Comment: @Bib should have been an example of an image where the effect is apparent. But it is not very helpful. I see.

Comment: This is the case when *photo of the monitor* is really needed, instead of screenshot. And yes, I understand it is hard to shoot the photo to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I believe it is impossible not only hard. The problem demostrates well when you have solid lighter blue area and you move your head towards the display and back, you see ceratin amount of filckering as the picture changes that is not good. With this monitor it is rather bad. Here with my ASUS at home it is quite acceptable and ok.

Comment: I have two U2412Ms, one I bought recently second hand and the other I've had for years. I see the exact same effect as you describe on the second hand monitor but not the other one. I also bought a new U2421E for my wife's PC last year and see the same thing on there!

Comment: @Sam I got replacement monitor of the same type and the problem is much less visible on it, so probably some pieces are worse and some better.

Answer (score 1):

I see no pixelation in the screenshot, so the problem is with the monitor.

Try to change the display parameters in Windows, such as resolution
and refresh rates. Do this also in the monitor's
On Screen Display (OSD).

If nothing helps to solve the problem, the monitor needs to be returned,
to be reimbursed or replaced.